# Burninate the `aspnet-core` tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I have noticed 2 synonymous tags with a single dot being the difference

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core

This tag has proper usage guidance, and over 5000 questions related to it, however this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-core

only has 13 (at the time of writing this question), and no user guidance.

It looks to me that they relate to the same thing. furthermore 
this tag will cause confusion for new users, it may hide the questions under it for older users who search by tags.

Should the latter tag be merged or burninated? and what is the rule for handling such tags?

Comment: The "rule" is that a synonym needs to be created and the tags need to be merged. But because the community cannot do that themselves, when you post this kind of thing on Meta, what inevitably happens is someone goes through cowboy-style, retagging all the questions. It works, but it's very annoying to anyone who follows these tags. And it doesn't stop the problem from re-occurring again in the future.

Comment: I wonder why people feel the need to create this tag http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39058422/revisions?

Comment: not looking hard enough i'd guess

Comment: @CodyGray can you elaborate on your "rule" because it is the first time I'm made aware of that. Maybe write a competing answer?

Comment: …it’s alive again … it’ll be dead at 3 UTC again.

Comment: I've retagged the question, hopefully it will be down for good

Comment: @rene I've written several answers about it before. Massive vigilante retags "bump" all of the affected questions, effectively launching a denial-of-service attack on the homepage of users who follow those tags. This sucks, because none of these retagged questions actually need our attention, and yet they are drowning out the questions that do. Like I said, there isn't really a good system other than getting a diamond to synonymize and merge the tags, but for some reason, it's extremely hard to get them to do that. Which means the community is left to do this the only way they can. :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like both me and [Tunaki](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32395858#32395858) re-tagged most of those questions. But we needed [Braiam](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39058422/revisions) to finish it off.

That tag <s>will be</s> is removed at 03:00 UTC

Comment: Tunaki sucks! He couldn't remove a miser tag! I had to do it! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39058422/revisions

Comment: How could I have missed that @Braiam ...

Comment: Now synonymized https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-core/synonyms